# Can we turn off Firebase (JavaScript) local synchronization?

Tags: javascript, firebase

I am using Firebase JS SDK. Whenever I set a value to a node (with transaction), the "value" event on that node is fired (even before the transaction callback is invoked.

I find this feature is really annoying (though such could be convenient in some other cases). Can I turn this local sync feature off?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can prevent the optimistic firing of local events for a `transaction` by passing in `false` for the `applyLocally` parameter. See https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/api/firebase/transaction.html

> `transaction(updateFunction, [onComplete], [applyLocally])`
>
> *applyLocally* *Boolean* *optional
>
> By default, events are raised each time the transaction update function runs. So if it is run multiple times, you may see intermediate states. You can set this to false to suppress these intermediate states and instead wait until the transaction has completed before events are raised.

Comment: is there a way to prevent optimistic for the push, set, remove, ... methods? I don't seem to find a way in the docs. v2.4.2